# How to test neural network after training

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I train a NN with pattern recognition toolbox in matlab
my input is a 3*42 matrix(42 samples 3 features)
my target is a 4*42 matrix which is 1 for true classes like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

I trained my NN now I want to test with new data it I use this code:

```
output = sim(net,testinputs)
```

or

```
a = net(testinputs)
```

but the Problems is it gives me a 4*3 matrix which is wrong, it should be a 4*1 matrix that one row is 1 another rows be 0.
What should I do to get the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Why yo don't try  with different shape of data, using column notations

Input data should be,according to your notation, try different
42*3, in other word you will have 3 columns(features) and 42 rows(samples)
then your target should not be in format 4*42 , it should be 42*4
(4 columns,42 rows)

Comment: I did that but the answer was wrong again and wasn't my point

Comment: What is your input in simulation? If it is 3 by vector , your simulation result should be 4 by 1, however , I guess, your input is  3 by 3 matrix so you are getting output 4 by 3 which is correct

Comment: my input:(for example): 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4;

Comment: my exact input: http://www.rodfile.com/2uji07h6ap52/input.txt    My target: http://www.rodfile.com/g5o9yh5i1yxr/target.txt